# Python Selenium check html element is present

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python selenium with firefox to check if a pages title

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(lambda x: 'Page 1' in driver.title or 'Page 2' in driver.title)
```

I am now wanting to also check if a HTML element is present, can I do this within this WebDriverWait statement or should I further process the result?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to reuse the same `WebDriverWait()` instance and issue a follow-up wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(lambda x: 'Page 1' in driver.title or 'Page 2' in driver.title)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myid")))
```

Or, you can also *combine them in a single function*:

```
def mywait(driver):
    if 'Page 1' in driver.title or 'Page 2' in driver.title:
        return EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myid"))(driver)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(mywait)
```